# Using featherlightGallery.js without a tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I'm using the [FeatherlightGallery](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) plugin for lightboxing on an image slider that just has images in it, not a tags then images, however it doesn't seem to load anything when clicking next/prev, just a blank lightbox. However the first image works. I get the console error:

`GET http://url.com/undefined 404 (Not Found)`

So it looks like it's not selecting the next image properly.

The JS to call the lightbox is:

```
$('.slider img').featherlightGallery({
    targetAttr: 'src',
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
        previous: '',
        next: ''
    }
});
```

and the html of those images is:

```
    <div class="slider">

        <img class="is-active" src="http://url.com/image.jpg" alt="" data-slide-id="0">

        <img src="http://url.com/image.jpg" alt="" data-slide-id="1">

        <img src="http://url.com/image.jpg" alt="" data-slide-id="2">

        <img src="http://url.com/image.jpg" alt="" data-slide-id="3">

    </div>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have fixed it by changing this line:

`$img[0].src = $nx.attr('href');`

to this:

`$img[0].src = (typeof $nx.attr('href') === 'undefined') ? $nx.attr('src') : $nx.attr('href');`